# Strategy alert doesn’t alert at the entry, but alert at the close of entry bar

Tags: pine-script

I created the strategy with the buy and sell condition. I created the alert, but the alert always send me the alert when the entry bars in the strategy has closed. How can I fix this.
Plus I want to be alerted exactly when my strategy has entry or close, which type of alert I need to set.

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are generated when actual trades are generated.
It is normal behaviour for the trades to be generated at the end of candle.

It is however possible for the conditions to be calculated at every tick by using

```
strategy(title="Example", calc_on_every_tick=true)
```

Please note that this can cause undesirable trades and this will not show up in the back-testing. Therefore I would recommend that you leave it as is